# Unable to commit changes to SVN server

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I've been trying to commit to the SVN server of a friend via Eclipse with subclipse 1.8.22, but if I enter its URL as `http://www.domainname.com/svn/my-proyect`, I get the error:

```
Repository has been moved
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://www.domainname.com/svn/my-proyect/!svn/me'; please relocate
```

and if I enter it without `www` (i.e. `http://www.domainname.com/svn/my-proyect`) I get the error:

```
Filesystem has no item svn: Commit failed (details follow): svn:
'/svn/my-project/!svn/me' path not found
```

I can do pretty much every SVN related actions but commiting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First Check with SVN properties.

Follow this step if that so.

press Alt + Shift + Q

Select Show view

then under SVN category add SVN Repositories

then right click go to Location Properties

Check URL in general tab